# hello how do set take profit and stop loss on atr bands at the first atr point as keeps recalculating setting new target

Tags: pine-script

hello im trying to set a take profit at the first atr point (upper blue line) when price crosses or even too it or set stoploss at the lowerband (red line) but as its atr will continue change and i cant figure out how to set take profit at first point as it keep recalculating. In the picture the dot on blue line is where i would like to set take profit.

[image: picture]
here code

```
when crossover buy and set take profit to first upper atr band and set stop loss to first lower atr band
ma= ta.sma(close,10)
buysign1= ta.crossover(close,ma)
plot(ma, color = color.blue)
plotshape(buysign1, title="Bullish Candles", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.tiny)

takeprofit= showTPBands ? scaledTPLong : na
stoploss = lowerATRBand
plot(takeprofit, title="Take Profit", color=color.blue)
plot(stoploss, title="Stop Loss", color=color.purple)

if buysign1
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,1)

if takeprofit 
    strategy.close("long", qty = 1 )
```

full code

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © TheTrdFloor
//
// In many strategies, it's quite common to use a scaled ATR to help define a stop-loss, and it's not uncommon to use it for take-profit targets
// as well.  While there are quite a few indicators that plot ATR bands already on TV, we could not find one that actually performed the exact 
// way that we wanted.  They all had at least one of the following gaps:
//   * The ATR offset was not configurable (usually hard-coded to be based off the high or low, while we generally prefer to use close)
//   * It would only print a single band (either the upper or lower), which would require the same indicator to be added twice
//   * The ATR scaling factor was either not configurable or only stepped in whole numbers (often time fractional factors like 1.5 yield better results)
//
// Also, when looking at some of the behaviors of the ATR bands, you can see that when price first levels out, you can draw a "consolidation zone" from
// the first peak of the upper ATR band to the first valley of the lower ATR band and look for price to break and close outside of that zone.  When that
// happens, price will usually make a notable move in that direction.
//
// While we have made some updates and enhancements to this indicator, and have every intention of continuing to do so as we find worthy opportunities
// for enhancement, credit is still due to the origianl author:  AlexanderTeaH
//
//@version=5
strategy('copy ATR Bands', overlay=true) // These had to be taken out as they're not compatible with plotting a table...   , timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=false

// Inputs
atrPeriod = input.int(title='ATR Period', defval=3, minval=1, group="ATR Bands Standard Settings", tooltip="This setting is used in the raw ATR value calculation.  Lower values will be more reactive to recent price movement, while higher values will better indicate loger-term trend.\n\n" +
                 "Most often this is set at either 14 or 21.\nDefault: 3")

// While it seemed like a nice idea at the time, having separately-configurable upper and lower bands just doesn't really seem that useful as 90% of the time the settings for both are the same.
// Therefore, We're going to simplify the config to make these settings unified for both bands, as it would otherwise just add even more confusion with the addition of take-profit bands as well...
//
// atrMultiplierUpper = input.float(title='ATR Upper Band Scale Factor', defval=2.5, step=0.1, minval=0.01, group="ATR Upper Band Settings", tooltip="Scaling factor (aka multiplier) for the ATR to use for plotting the ATR bands.  " +
//                     "This will usually be between 1 and 3.")
// srcUpper = input.source(title='ATR Upper Offset Source', defval=close, group="ATR Upper Band Settings", tooltip="This setting determines the offset point for ATR bands.  " +
//                     "For this band, 'high' and 'close' (default) are generally the most appropriate values.")
//
atrMultiplier = input.float(title='ATR Band Scale Factor', defval=2.5, step=0.1, minval=0.01, group="ATR Bands Standard Settings", tooltip="Scaling factor (aka multiplier) for the ATR to use for plotting the ATR bands.  " +
                     "This will usually be between 1 and 3.\n\nDefault: 2.5")
// On second thought, I'm going to nix this setting and force it to be the "close" source.  Having the ability to offset based on the wicks was a nice idea, but doesn't really seem to have any notable practical application.
atrSourceRef = "close"
//atrSourceRef = input.string(title='ATR Upper Offset Source', defval="close", options=["close","wicks"], group="ATR Bands Standard Settings", tooltip="This setting determines the offset point for ATR bands.  " +
//                     "The default value 'close' should be your go-to, but 'wicks' might provide a bit more breathing room in securities that tend to have large wicks.")
//
// See above - these are deprecated and no longer used...
//
// atrMultiplierLower = input.float(title='ATR Lower Band Scale Factor', defval=2.5, step=0.1, minval=0.01, group="ATR Lower Band Settings", tooltip="Scaling factor (aka multiplier) for the ATR to use for plotting the ATR bands.  " +
//                     "This will usually be between 1 and 3.")
// srcLower = input.source(title='ATR Lower Offset Source', defval=close, group="ATR Lower Band Settings", tooltip="This setting determines the offset point for ATR bands.  " +
//                     "For this band, 'low' and 'close' (default) are generally the most appropriate values.")
//
//
// Take-Profit band settings
showTPBands = input.bool(title="Show opposite bands for take-profit zones", defval=false, tooltip="If enalbled, the existing ATR bands will be treated as 'stop-loss' bands, and 'take-profit' bands will be plotted " +
                     "to depict potential take-profit targets that are scaled based on the 'stop-loss' band and an additional reward/risk scaling factor (see below).\n\nDefault: Unchecked", group="Take-Profit Settings")
tpScaleFactor = input.float(title="Take-Profit Scale Factor", defval=1.5, minval=1, step=0.1, tooltip="This is a secondary scaling factor used based on the 'stop-loss' ATR bands to calculate and plot a potential take-profit target.\n\n" + 
                     "The easiest way to think of this is as a desired reward/risk ratio, where the primary ATR Bands represent the risk/stop-loss.\n\nDefault: 1.5")
//
//
// As an added bonus, give the option to plot a table containing exact figures for all of the bands...
// Functional settings
showTable = input.bool(title="Show Table for Stops and Targets", defval=false, group="Table Settings", tooltip="If enabled, a table will be placed on-chart showing exact values for both stop bands, as well as optional take-profit bands/targets.\n\n" +
                     "Note: Take-profit values are based on the 'Take-Profit Scale Factor' setting above.\n\nDefault: Unchecked")
allowTableRepainting = input.bool(title="Allow Table Repainting", defval=false, group="Table Settings", tooltip="If enabled, table data will show real-time values, which will inherently repaint.  This may be desirable for people preparing to enter prior " +
                     "to candle close, but should be used with extreme caution.\n\nDefault: Unchecked")
showTPinTable = input.bool(title="Include additional rows/columns to display take-profit values.", defval=false, group="Table Settings", tooltip="If enabled, additional table rows/columns will be drawn and populated with take-profit band/target values.\n\n" +
                     "Note: Take-profit values are based on the 'Take-Profit Scale Factor' setting above.\n\nDefault: Unchecked")
//
// Display settings
alignTableVertically = input.bool(title="Align Table Vertically", defval=true, group="Table Settings", tooltip="If enabled, the table will be re-aligned to display vertically (headers to the left) instead of horizontally (headers on top).\n\nDefault: Checked")
tablePosition = input.string(title="Table Location", defval="Bottom Right", options=["Top Right","Top Left","Top Center","Middle Right","Middle Left","Middle Center","Bottom Right","Bottom Left","Bottom Center"], group="Table Settings", 
                     tooltip='This setting controls the position on the chart where the table will be located.\n\nDefault: Bottom Right')
tableColor = input.color(title="Table Color: ", defval=color.rgb(0, 175, 200, 20), group="Table Settings", inline="A")
tableTextHeaderColor = input.color(title="Table Header Color: ", defval=color.rgb(255, 255, 0, 0), group="Table Settings", tooltip="These settings determine the colors used for the table cell borders/outlines, and the text inside the table cells used as data headers.", inline="A")
tableTextColor = input.color(title="Table Text Color: ", defval=color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 0), group="Table Settings", tooltip="This setting determines the color used for the text inside the table cells.", inline="B")
// tableTooltipColor = input.color(title="Table Tooltip Color: ", defval=color.rgb(255, 75, 255, 0), group="Table Display Settings", tooltip="This setting determines the color used for any cell tooltips.") // Not used
tableLongBGColor = input.color(title="Table Background Color - Long: ", defval=color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 90), group="Table Settings", inline="C")
tableShortBGColor = input.color(title="Short: ", defval=color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 80), group="Table Settings", tooltip="These settings determine the background fill colors used for long/short position info.", inline="C")


// Functions
//
// Function to convert the input "source" to a proper "source"
getBandOffsetSource(srcIn, isUpperBand) =>
    // Initialize the return to our fail-safe 'close', which is also the default input, then update thru the switch statement
    ret = close
    switch srcIn
        "close" => ret := close
        "wicks" => ret := isUpperBand ? high : low
        => ret := close
    ret
//
// Function to convert table position input to a an appropriate argument
getTablePosition(posIn) =>
    posOut = position.bottom_right
    switch (posIn)
        "Top Right" => posOut := position.top_right
        "Top Left" => posOut := position.top_left
        "Top Center" => posOut := position.top_center
        "Middle Right" => posOut := position.middle_right
        "Middle Left" => posOut := position.middle_left
        "Middle Center" => posOut := position.middle_center
        "Bottom Right" => posOut := position.bottom_right
        "Bottom Left" => posOut := position.bottom_left
        "Bottom Center" => posOut := position.bottom_center
        => posOut := position.bottom_right
    posOut
    
// ATR
atr = ta.atr(atrPeriod)
scaledATR = atr * atrMultiplier
upperATRBand = getBandOffsetSource(atrSourceRef, true) + scaledATR
lowerATRBand = getBandOffsetSource(atrSourceRef, false) - scaledATR
//
// Since we can calcualte ATR bands based on either close or wicks, we need to be sure to normalize the true distance
// from the close to the "stop band" before we can then apply our take-profit scaler and calculate the TP bands...
scaledTPLong = close + ((close - lowerATRBand) * tpScaleFactor)
scaledTPShort = close - ((upperATRBand - close) * tpScaleFactor)

// OG ATR Band Plotting
plot(upperATRBand, title="Upper ATR Band", color=color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 50), linewidth=2)
plot(lowerATRBand, title="Lower ATR Band", color=color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50), linewidth=2)

// TP band plots
plot(showTPBands ? scaledTPLong : na, title="Upper Take-Profit Band", color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 80), linewidth=1)
plot(showTPBands ? scaledTPShort : na, title="Lower Take-Profit Band", color=color.rgb(255, 255, 0, 80), linewidth=1)

// ATR and TP table...
if (showTable)
    // It's nice that TV will automagically shrink/reposition table cells to not have gaps if a specific row/column are missing,
    // so we can define the table to the max number of rows/columns possible for this indicator in any configuration and let TV handle the "shrinking".
    var atrTable = table.new(position=getTablePosition(tablePosition), columns=8, rows=8)
    //
    // Set the base table styles...
    table.set_border_width(atrTable, 1)
    table.set_frame_width(atrTable, 1)
    table.set_border_color(atrTable, tableColor)
    table.set_frame_color(atrTable, tableColor)
    //
    // Since we're giving the option to display the table with 2 different formats (horizontal vs vertical), we need to build out both variations and
    // incorporate a method to switch from one to the other based on the 'alignTableVertically' user input setting.  While we probably COULD do
    // conditional logic inside the 'table.cell' functions, it will be far more intuitive to "read" if we simply break it into an 'if-else' clause.
    // 
    // While this WILL result in a pretty notable duplication of code, it's acceptable in this case as we have a finite number of options (2).
    //
    // Vertical orientation
    if (alignTableVertically)
        // Define the Title/Header cells
        table.cell(atrTable, 0, 0, text="Long ATR Stop", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor, tooltip="Test")
        table.cell(atrTable, 0, 1, text="Long ATR Stop Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 0, 2, text="Long ATR TP", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 0, 3, text="Long ATR TP Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        table.cell(atrTable, 0, 4, text="Short ATR Stop", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        table.cell(atrTable, 0, 5, text="Short ATR Stop Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 0, 6, text="Short ATR TP", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 0, 7, text="Short ATR TP Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        //
        // Now for table values for each header...
        // Start with Long position...
        table.cell(atrTable, 1, 0, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? lowerATRBand : lowerATRBand[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor, tooltip="Test")
        table.cell(atrTable, 1, 1, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? close - lowerATRBand : close[1] - lowerATRBand[1])), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 1, 2, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? scaledTPLong : scaledTPLong[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 1, 3, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? scaledATR * tpScaleFactor : scaledATR[1] * tpScaleFactor)), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        // Now the Short position...
        table.cell(atrTable, 1, 4, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? upperATRBand : upperATRBand[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor, tooltip="Test 2")
        table.cell(atrTable, 1, 5, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? upperATRBand - close : upperATRBand[1] - close[1])), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 1, 6, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? scaledTPShort : scaledTPShort[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 1, 7, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? scaledATR * tpScaleFactor : scaledATR[1] * tpScaleFactor)), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        
        
        
    //
    // Horizontal orientation
    else
        // Define the Title/Header cells
        table.cell(atrTable, 0, 0, text="Long ATR Stop", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor, tooltip="Test")
        table.cell(atrTable, 1, 0, text="Long ATR Stop Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 2, 0, text="Long ATR TP", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 3, 0, text="Long ATR TP Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        table.cell(atrTable, 4, 0, text="Short ATR Stop", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        table.cell(atrTable, 5, 0, text="Short ATR Stop Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 6, 0, text="Short ATR TP", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 7, 0, text="Short ATR TP Dist", text_color=tableTextHeaderColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        //
        // Now for table values for each header...
        // Start with Long position...
        table.cell(atrTable, 0, 1, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? lowerATRBand : lowerATRBand[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor, tooltip="Test")
        table.cell(atrTable, 1, 1, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? close - lowerATRBand : close[1] - lowerATRBand[1])), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 2, 1, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? scaledTPLong : scaledTPLong[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 3, 1, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? scaledATR * tpScaleFactor : scaledATR[1] * tpScaleFactor)), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableLongBGColor)
        // Now the Short position...
        table.cell(atrTable, 4, 1, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? upperATRBand : upperATRBand[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor, tooltip="Test 2")
        table.cell(atrTable, 5, 1, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? upperATRBand - close : upperATRBand[1] - close[1])), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
        if (showTPinTable)
            table.cell(atrTable, 6, 1, text=str.tostring(allowTableRepainting ? scaledTPShort : scaledTPShort[1], format.mintick), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
            // If the TP scale factor is exactly 1, we can nix the TP distance columns as it will be exactly the same as the stop distance.
            if (tpScaleFactor != 1)
                table.cell(atrTable, 7, 1, text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(allowTableRepainting ? scaledATR * tpScaleFactor : scaledATR[1] * tpScaleFactor)), text_color=tableTextColor, bgcolor=tableShortBGColor)
                
//--------------------
// when crossover buy and set take proft to first upper atr band and set stop loss to first lower atr band

ma= ta.sma(close,10)
buysign1= ta.crossover(close,ma)
plot(ma, color = color.blue)
plotshape(buysign1, title="Bullish Candles", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.tiny)


takeprofit= showTPBands ? scaledTPLong : na
stoploss = lowerATRBand
plot(takeprofit, title="Take Profit", color=color.blue)
plot(stoploss, title="Stop Loss", color=color.purple)

if buysign1
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long,1)

if  takeprofit 
    strategy.close("long", qty = 1 )
```

Not sure where to start been staring at screen for a while.

Comment: Please just use the language version tag for the language you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store those values in a `var` variable when the cross happens.

```
var float tp_price = na

tp_cross = ta.crossover(close, tp_line)    // Here the tp_line is the line which you want to use as TP
tp_price := tp_cross ? tp_line : tp_price  // If there is a new cross, store the value in tp_price. Keep the old value otherwise
```